# HTML img behavior - why no margin when floated?

Tags: css

In this example of image gallery:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float_elements

```
<head>
<style>
.thumbnail 
{
     float:left;
     width:110px;
     height:90px;
     margin:5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Image Gallery</h3>
<p>Try resizing the window to see what happens when the images does not have enough    room.</p>
<img class="thumbnail" src="klematis3_small.jpg" width="116" height="90">
<img class="thumbnail" src="klematis4_small.jpg" width="120" height="90">
</body>
</html>
```

If width is removed from .thumbnail class then the images are placed next to one another without a space in between. But for regular image elements without float, there seems to be some margin automatically. I need to understand the general behavior. The behavior of float is that they are placed next to each other. Why is affecting margins of image elements?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [block elements](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/) can have margins.

add:

`display:block` to your css

Comment: I used display:block for the .thumbnail. Yet there is no margin. :(

Comment: Baloney. Change it to 50px and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Each image has their own width size. If you didn't set the width size in the class, then the images will not be aligned nicely. If you're declaring the width in the class, it's like you create a container for that image where no matter what is the width of that image, it will be resize into 110 pixels accordingly. And yes, the float will align all the images next to each other.